# How could I get the full URL in apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, salesforcedx, apexrest

How can I take the full url without affecting the "&"
if i redirect to this page: https://XXX.XXX.force.com?pay=BXXXB&PA83747474&TOKEN=23444848
for example. I catch the url using:

String url = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('pay');

but if i print url only got: BXXXB

i cannot be able to get the full url even with the &.

I would like to get the full url : "BXXXB&PA83747474&TOKEN=23444848"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl()`

Relevant: [PageReference class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_PageReference_methods.htm)